# Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, union

u"Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. map<string,int> <> structint:int,long:null at the Nth column of the second table.

Here is how the schema looks like:

Dataset 1

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- int: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- long: null (nullable = true)
```

DataSet 2

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Unable to do union operation on DF when using following:

```
data= dataset1_df.union(dataset2_df)
```

How to solve this?

Updated:
I would like to change schema such as:

DataSet 1

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long
```

DataSet2

```
 root
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- count: long
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be typecasting one of the dataframe to match another as below-

```scala
 val df1 = spark.sql("select 'foo' name, named_struct('int', 1, 'long', null) count")
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+-----+
      * |name|count|
      * +----+-----+
      * |foo |[1,] |
      * +----+-----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- count: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- int: integer (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- long: null (nullable = true)
      */

    val df2 = spark.sql("select 'bar' name, map('2', 3) count")
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----+--------+
      * |name|count   |
      * +----+--------+
      * |bar |[2 -> 3]|
      * +----+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- name: string (nullable = false)
      * |-- count: map (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- key: string
      * |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
      */

    df1.withColumn("count",
      map($"count.int".cast("string"), $"count.long".cast("integer")))
      .union(df2)
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+--------+
      * |name|count   |
      * +----+--------+
      * |foo |[1 ->]  |
      * |bar |[2 -> 3]|
      * +----+--------+
      */
```